# Button behaving globally and not for each item in Salesforce LWC

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am quite new to Lighting Web Component. However, I have some experience with other component base frameworks.

I'm creating a button for each item and when the button is clicked for each item. It applies to all items. In other words, when one clicks 'Extend' it is meant to show a date input for that specific item but it shows too all of them. This is how my code looks like:

```
<template>
<template if:true={subscriptionData}>
    <template for:each={subscriptionData} for:item="subscriptionItem">
            <div key={subscriptionItem.Id}>
                <div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
                        <div class="slds-col custom-card-title-container">
                            <h2 class="custom-title">{subscriptionItem.SBQQ__ProductName__c}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col button-custom">
                            <lightning-button label="Extend" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleShowEditEndDate} class="slds-m-right_none custom-margin"></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-top_xx-small">
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                                    <span>Start Date</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <span>{subscriptionItem.SBQQ__StartDate__c}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                                    <span>End Date</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <span>{subscriptionItem.SBQQ__EndDate__c}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-m-bottom_xx-small">
                                    <span>Quantity</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <span>{subscriptionItem.SBQQ__Quantity__c}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <template if:true={showEditField}>
                        <lightning-layout multiple-rows class="slds-m-top_xx-small">
                            <lightning-layout-item size="8">
                                <lightning-input 
                                    type="date" 
                                    name="endDateInput" 
                                    label="End Date" 
                                    variant="label-inline"
                                    >
                                </lightning-input>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-layout>
                    </template>
                    <hr class = "custom-line">
                </div>
            </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

```
export default class ExtendCPQSubscriptionLWC extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@track subscriptionData;
@track columns = columns;
showEditField = false

@wire(getSubscriptionsLWC, { recordId: '$recordId'})
loadFoundSubscriptions({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('OK');
        console.log(data);
        this.subscriptionData = data;
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('ERR ' + JSON.stringify(error));
       
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any input thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have common *showEditField* used to control visibility/addition of date input. My recommendation is to move that information inside *subscriptionData* and update the track variable. This would trigger re-render of UI and only show that field for item, for which Extend button was clicked